# Problem with loading json file from url using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

**So here is the code that i wrote, my assignment is this:**
I have json file from here:http://ergast.com/api/f1/+SEASON+/drivers.json
There are two SEASONS: 2016 and 2017 so i need two json files accordingly.
I have to make three lists.
The first should contain json file from season 2016 so, http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016/drivers.json
and should contain only first name and last name
The second one should contain json file from season 2017, so
http://ergast.com/api/f1/2017/drivers.json
and also should contain first name and last name
And on the third list should contain my favorite drivers so it needs to be sortable ui so i can drag and drop there or vice versa and when there are people on the third list and by that i mean first name and last name and by clicking at the whole name there should be addiditonal information like number, date of birth, nationality.. I made that with jquery ui tooltip.
The tooltip is working but when i click on the second tab i can't go back to the first
Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <title>Formula 1</title>
      <script>
         function getEntries(u,l) {
             $.ajax({
                url: u,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                 success: function (data) {
                     $.each(data.Drivers, function (i,item) {
                         var name = item.givenName;
                         var surname = item.familyName;
                         var num = item.permanentNumber;
                         var date = item.dateOfBirth;
                         var nationality = item.nationality;
                         var strana = item.url;
                         l.append("<div class='container2'><ol><li>Name: '+name+', Surname: '+surname+'</li></ol>");
                     });
                 }


             });
         }
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var u1 = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016/drivers.json";
             var u2 = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2017/drivers.json";

             var l1 = $('#list1');
             var l2 = $('#list2');

             getEntries(u1,l1);
             $("#tabs").tabs({
                 beforeActivate: function (uevenet,ui) {
                     if(ui.newTab.index()==0) {
                         if($("#list1 li").size()==0) {
                             getEntries(u1,l1);
                         }
                     }
                     else if(ui.newTab.index()==1)
                     {
                         if($("#list2 li").size == 0)
                         {
                             getEntries(u2,l2);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             });

             $("#list3").sortable({});

             $( "#list1" ).sortable({
                 connectWith: "#list3"
             });
             $( "#list2" ).sortable({
                 connectWith: "#list3"
             });
             $( "#list1, #list2, #list3" ).disableSelection();

             $(document).tooltip({
                 items: "#list3 li, #list2 li, #list1 li",
                 content: function(){
                     var el = $(this);
                     var br = el.attr("num");
                     var datum = el.attr("date");
                     var nacionalnost = el.attr("nationality");
                     var link = el.attr("strana");

                     return "Number of driver: " +  br +
                            "Datum na raganje" + datum +
                            "Nacionalnost" + nacionalnost +
                            "Url do vozac" + link;
                 }
             });


         })

      </script>
      <style>
         .container{
         float:left;
         margin:20px;
         padding: 5px;
         }
         .container1{
         float:right;
         padding: 5px;
         }
         .container2{
         width: 500px;
         }
         .li:nth-child(odd) { background: white;}
         .li:nth-child(even) { background: lightblue; }
         .container{
         border-left: 1px lightgray solid;
         }
         #list1, #list2, #list3{
         list-style-type: none;
         }
         .row-selected{
         background:lightblue;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="tabs" style="min-height:5000px">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">2016 Drivers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">2017 Drivers</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="tabs-1">
            <div class="container" style="float:left">
               <strong>2016 Drivers</strong>
               <ul id="list1"></ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="tabs-2">
            <div class="container" style="float:left">
               <strong>2017 Drivers</strong>
               <ul id="list2"></ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="fav" class="container1" style="float:left">
            <strong>Favourites</strong>
            <ul id="list3">
               <li>Drop you favourite drivers here...</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the Json return object value
 $.each(**data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers**, function (i,item) {...}

Fix " and ' mix.
  Name: **"+name+", Surname: "+surname+"**

Use length instead of size
  if($("#list1  li").**length** ==0 )

For more error message see the console window in Developer tools.

Comment: Isn't it $.each(data.MRData.MRData) because like you told me i got and error saying DriverTable undefined

Comment: console.log(data) and check the return object. data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers works.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DriverTable' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (kol1.html?_ijt=ifi338tcgksrbcml628p0jmvkk:17)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (kol1.html?_ijt=ifi338tcgksrbcml628p0jmvkk:16)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: This is with using $.each(data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers, function (i,item)

Comment: I got it it was with the variables i used item.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers.familyName instead of item.FamilyName thanks by the way

Comment: $(document).tooltip({
                 items: "#list3 li, #list2 li, #list1 li",
                 content: function(){
                     var el = $(this);
                     var br = el.attr("num");
                     var datum = el.attr("date");
                     var nacionalnost = el.attr("nationality");
                     var link = el.attr("strana");
                     return "Number of driver: " +  br    "Datum na raganje" + datum +
                            "Nacionalnost" + nacionalnost +
                            "Url do vozac" + link;